# Angular project specify multiple host names under same project

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a multi-store site which needs to be setup in a angular project, i changed the default localhost:4200 to my custom domain and i have all my domains listed in my hosts file under the same ip.

Currently when i run yarn start it loads my angular project on my domain rather than localhost:4200 which works great.

In angular.json i have set the following

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "spartacus:build",
        "disableHostCheck": true,
        "host": "my-store-de.local",
        "port": 4200
      },
```

How can i alter this hosts property to allow for multiple domains so if i went to my-store-ch.local for example it would load the project on that domain too. I have had a look at similar cases but all of them seem to be in firebase which i am not using this is just for local development for now any help or someone who could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`ng serve` is aimed for development purposes only so it doesn't support what you need.
You can start your project on a `127.0.0.1` IP address (instead of domain `localhost`)  if you bind custom domains to 127.0.0.1 then everything should work.

Another solution is to start the app on `localhost:4200` but additionally setup `nginx` web server locally (or Apache it's up to you) setup there few local domains + use it in proxy mode, something like this

```
server {
  server_name my-store-de.local;
  listen 80;

  location / {
     index index.html;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
  }
}
```